# Auto width scroll bar in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-visualization

I using the Google Chart for in my HTML5 Project. which takes the JSON values ( from DB ) to plot the graph.

my need is to have a scroll bar if the datas are more than 5 to 6 in the JSON Value.
I have created the sample attached link via JSFiddle.

currently i have given 22 values. i need the same effect when the JSON value has 3 or 4 values. There shd not be any change in the bar width it should maintain the same width even if the JSON has 50 values.

Kindly provide me the solution thank you so much. :)

Here is the link : - http://jsfiddle.net/gK9r7/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hsakX/

Set the bar.groupWidth option to fix the width of the bars. Then make the width of the chart a function of the bar-width and the number of bars to be displayed:

```
var options = {            
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
    width: data.getNumberOfRows() * 65,
    bar: {groupWidth: 20}
};
```

Set the overflow-x on the containing div to scroll:

```
#chart_div {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;     
 width: 500px;
 height: 550px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but can tell me how to avoid the unwanted space on the left side of the graph.Latest Fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/hsakX/1/

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QGtvL/. To remove the left margin set chartArea: {left: 0}

Comment: Hey excellent and thanks for your help and if you see the output . it has some unwanted space at the right side too even after the legend is over how to trim those things. it will be better if i get the scroll just exactly to the graph. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try this: chartArea: {left: 0, width: '100%'}

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help but the left side values and right legend goes missing right ? and one more thing ? shd the json values in js have to be at the top of the body or it can even in bottom

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15881/discussion-between-greg-ross-and-harry)

Comment: as @Harry said, the mentioned solution is scrolling all chart wrapper div - including the legend and title. Is there any solution within Google charts documentation, so only horizontal axis will be scrolling, and vertical axis (and all legends) will be always visible?

Comment: Hi,  am looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/nAa33/  with google chart... is it possible? any example? thanks in advance...

Comment: See the accepted answer here...this is pretty close to what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852511/horizontal-scroll-with-vertical-axes-static-in-google-charts