# Horizontal scroll with vertical axes static in google charts

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I am using `google chart` in my App and I wanted to implement scroll. I could do it by styling the container div.

But the problem is that it scrolls the entire graph with the axis. How to scroll horizontally only the chart area and keep the vertical axis static?

Comment: Have you tried the overflow option?

Comment: I am now using the overflow option itself.But that moves the y-axis inwards on scrolling horizontally.My need is to keep the vertical axis static and scroll only the chart area.

Comment: @Adidev Did you find the solution for it?.If Yes let me know how you approached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visualization API has a built-in control to handle chart scrolling: the [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like '`overflow-x`' is what you are looking for

in the script that creates the chart, be sure to add the following:

```
var options = {
                'title': 'Chart title',
                'hAxis': { title: 'axis title', titleTextStyle: { color: 'blue' } },
                'width': data.getNumberOfRows() * 65,
                'height': 300,
                'bar': {groupWidth: 20}
            };
```

this way the width will be set by the number of bars.
the next thing you'll need is to set the overflow-x property:

```
<style type="text/css">
        #chart_div {
            overflow-x: scroll;
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
```

what will happen now, is that the chart will be 500px width, and if you'll have more data than that - you'll get a horizontal scroll bar

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my requirement is to hold the y-axis in the left most part static and scroll the x-axis alone