# How to have fixed Y-Axis when using chart range filter

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to use the chart range filter, but whenever I use the scroll bar with their demo, the Y-Axis is not fixed. I am trying to make it so that when scrolled, the Y-Axis is fixed and stays in its place. Is it possible to have this? Here's the demo [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter).

Comment: @WhiteHat I want an X-Axis scroll bar when the X-Axis has many ticks. Just like the demo here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter But when I scroll through the scroll bar in the demo, the Y-axis is not static. I'd like it so that when I scroll through the X-Axis, the Y-Axis is still there

Comment: that's sort of the point of the ChartRangeFilter, use it to narrow the chart area, see --> [Horizontal scroll with vertical axes static in google charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852511/horizontal-scroll-with-vertical-axes-static-in-google-charts)

Comment: It narrows the chart area, but I want to use the scrolling bar to see the other points. When using the scroll bar, the y-axis is not fixed