# Adding scroll bar for Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to add a scroll bar to my chart in Google charts, except I want the Y-Axis to be fixed when I scroll to see other x-axis ticks. I am trying to work with ChartRangeFilter, but it seems that this only works for dates and not strings. Basically, I have a column chart that has many xAxis ticks. If I show all the ticks without a scrollbar, they will get cluttered. I'd like to make it so that I have a scroll bar to scroll to see the remaining xAxis ticks. I've tried using `explorer: {axis: 'horizontal'}` but it does not let me scroll through when dragging my mouse. I'd also like a scrollbar instead. Note: I could use `x-axis: overflow` but when scrolling this way, it hides the Y-Axis. I need to see the Y-Axis while scrolling

Comment: what about drawing two charts side by side -- limit one to only show the axis, and the other only show the chart area -- would need to sync y-axis ticks -- then they would be in separate containers, easily apply overflow...

Comment: @WhiteHat Is there a way to use ChartRangeFilter though?

Comment: @WhiteHat I mean is there a way to use only one chart and applying a chartrangefilter to that chart?

Comment: @WhiteHat Wouldn't it be better if I put the same exact chart inside the same container and then position the inner one so that the Y-axis of the outer one shows the Y-Axis?

Comment: @WhiteHat Couldn't I apply overflow in the newly created div that's appended to that container? So essentially it's a div within a div?

Comment: @WhiteHat But do you think this can be accomplished using chartrangefilter?

Comment: not by itself, like i commented on [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45022110/5090771), the range filter is meant to prevent the need for a scroll bar -- there aren't any standard options for a fixed y-axis...

Comment: @WhiteHat When I use the ChartRangeFilter, it is exactly what I want, but how do I implement it with the stringed ticks I have instead of dates?

Comment: the range filter only supports a continuous axis -- date or number types -- but you can use object notation for each tick to provide both the value of the tick and the formatted value of the tick -- `{v: 0, f: 'any string you want to display'}` -- or -- `{v: new Date(2017, 6, 17), f: 'again, any string'}` -- the formatted value will be displayed on the axis label...