# How to remove the scroll bar from the column chart in java script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-visualization, column-chart

I  have created  a column  chart which will be popped up by clicking a marker in a Google Map using  the google.visualization.ColumnChart. A **div** has been created upon which the Column Chart is being implanted.

```
var node = document.createElement('div')
```

It works  fine but  my  problem  is the scroll  bar  which  i  don't  require.So,  can  anyone prefer  how to  take out  the scroll bar from the chart.

And this is my code part for the column chart

```
    function drawChart(marker) {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();


         //For column chart
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
        data.addRows([
            ['1', 8, 'color: #ac6598'],
            ['2', 7, 'color: #ac6598'],
            ['1', 7, 'color: #3fb0e9'],
            ['2', 9, 'color: #3fb0e9'],
            ['1', 10, 'color: #42c698'],
            ['2', 8, 'color: #42c698'],
            ['1', 8, 'color: #42c98'],
            ['2', 4, 'color: #42c98']

        ]);

            // Set chart options
            var options = {           
                width:200, height:150,           
                vAxis: { gridlines: { color: 'transparent'},textPosition: 'none'}
            };

            var node        = document.createElement('div'),
                infoWindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
                chart       = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(node);

                chart.draw(data, options);
                infoWindow.setContent(node);
                infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(),marker);
          }
 google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

I have already seen this [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136331/auto-width-scroll-bar-in-google-chart) but somehow could not fit into the requirement.

So please help me with this . And thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the scrollbar will result the user not being able to see the content inside the column if the size of the column is not large enough.

To remove the scrollbar, what you can do is create a div and set its css property of overflow to hidden, but keep in mind some content inside the column may not be visible if it overflows.

Code:

```css
#column
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="column">
    //your content goes here...
</div>
```

However a better approach would be to hide the scrollbar while allowing the user to scroll. This way there is no scrollbar, but the user can still scroll and see the hidden content. To do this, you can create a parent div for div column, and set overflow hidden of the parent div and overflow-y to scroll for the child div column.

Code:

```css
#content
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#column
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="column">
        //your content goes here...
    </div>
</div>
```

Overflow-y will allow the user to scroll if the content overflows vertically, from top to bottom.

Comment: what I meant to say is that, the column chart is created on a google map chart after clicking on the markers. And a div is created at runtime (var node        = document.createElement('div')) and the column chart is being implanted on that. How can i fit the "overflow: hidden" there

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I misread your question. Anyway I can help. Use this and it should remove the scrollbar from the popup info window. Add this to your CSS file and it should do the job: #map_canvas div {
 line-height: normal ! important;
}

Comment: After doing a little more research, this seems to be a problem on FireFox only. Here is a solution: http://www.canbike.org/information-technology/2013/11/01/firefox-infowindow-scrollbar-fix-google-maps-api-v3.html What browser are you using? Also let me know if that fixes it, I can't test it at the moment, sorry.

Comment: the final fix:  node.style.overflow = "hidden";     thanks a lot

Comment: Haha, glad you figured it out. I am sorry I couldn't you help there much.