# Adding a new line to Google chart without shifting the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm having trouble using google charts stacked graphs to display a 'dynamic' graph, by dynamic I mean that every time I draw the graph, I add a new row of data.

The problem is that when I add the new row, the entire graph proportion changes.

Link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9u7ry7x5/11/).

HTML:

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<button onclick='DrawChart();'>Draw Chart</button>
```

CSS:

```
#chartdiv{
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: solid;
}
```

JS:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
// create legend
var legend = ['School', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
// create table
var dataTable = [legend];
// create line
var line = ['line', 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.33, 0 , 0.12, 0.15];

function DrawChart() {
    dataTable.push(line);



    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataTable);
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    var options_fullStacked = {
        isStacked: 'percent',
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        height: data.getNumberOfRows() * 110,
        width: 615,
        bar: {  groupWidth: 50  },
        hAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            ticks: [0, .25, .5, .75, 1]
        },

    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("chartdiv"));
    chart.draw(view, options_fullStacked);
}
```

I saw a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136331/auto-width-scroll-bar-in-google-chart), which I tried to learn from and make the changes accordingly, but it didn't help.

The best way to understand what I need help with is to enter the JSFiddle link and click the draw chart button a few times, each time you click it a new row will be added to the chart. So just try clicking it a few times and you'll see that things are starting to get messy after a while.

Ideally what I'm trying to achieve is that after the 2nd, 3rd (and so on) click I won't notice that the entire graph we loaded, I will only notice that a new row was added.

I would really appreciate help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. After playing with the graph for a while I found a way to overcome most of the bugs I had.

The main issues were the changing height and width, and that after a few runs the graph was starting to lose its structure.

The changes I made include:

- Setting a fixed width.
- Setting a min height and also making some adjustments to the size value.
- Setting a fixed font size - that's what caused the graph to lose its shape.

I've included the updated code below. (looks much better in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9u7ry7x5/15/))

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
});
// create legend
var legend = ['School', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
// create table
var dataTable = [legend];
// create line
var lines = [
  ['line', 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.33, 0, 0.12, 0.15],
  ['line', 0.1, 0.3, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.12, 0.23]
];
var i = 0;

function DrawChart() {
  dataTable.push(lines[(i++) % 2]);



  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataTable);
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  var height = Math.max(180, data.getNumberOfRows() * 85);

  var options_fullStacked = {
    isStacked: 'percent',
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      maxLines: 3
    },
    height: height,
    width: 720,
    bar: {
      groupWidth: 50
    },
    hAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      ticks: [0, .25, .5, .75, 1],
      title: "p"
    },
    chartArea: {
      left: 100,
      top: 30,
      width: 600
    },
    fontSize: 14
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("chartdiv"));
  chart.draw(view, options_fullStacked);
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<button onclick='DrawChart();'>Draw Chart</button>
```