# Google chart horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Here is my chart so far:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yv936sr/5/)

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);


  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Day', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data1 compare', 'data2 compare', 'data3 compare', 'data4 compare', '', ''],
     [0.85,  165, 938,  522, 998, null, null, null, null,  614.6, 500],
     [1.15,  null, null, null, null, 165, 938,  522, 998,  614.6, 510],
     [1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, null ],       
     [1.85,  135, 1120, 599, 1268, null, null, null, null, 682, 530],
     [2.15, null, null, null, null, 165, 938,  522, 998, 682, 540],
     [14,  135, 1120, 599, 1268, null, null, null, null, 682, 530],
     [16, null, null, null, null, 165, 938,  522, 998, 682, 540]
  ]);

var options = {
  title : 'Chart',
  vAxes: [
    {title: 'foo'},
    {title: 'bar'}
  ],
  //hAxis: { ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]},
  hAxis: { 
    ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,  16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
    textStyle : {
        fontSize: 9 // or the number you want
    }
  },
  seriesType: 'bars',
  bar: { groupWidth: 1000 },
  isStacked: true,
  legend: 'none',
  interpolateNulls: true,
  series: {
        0: {
            targetAxisIndex: 0
        },
        4: {
            targetAxisIndex: 0
        },
        8: {
            targetAxisIndex: 1,
            type: 'line'
        },
        9: {
            targetAxisIndex: 1,
            type: 'line'
        }
    }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>

<!-- language: lang-html -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

I wanted to ask if there is a way to make elements in chart make bigger, but have a horizontal scrollbar with vAxes labels fixed and always visible?

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136331/auto-width-scroll-bar-in-google-chart) has what you're looking for.

Comment: Not really, I want labels to be fixed and only chart should be scrollable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Charts has this explorer feature whereby you can scroll and zoom in/out of the Chart. However, no buttons or scroll bar will be displayed. You will have to use your mouse to drag and move horizontally on the chart displayed.

To allow this feature, simply add `explorer: {axis: 'horizontal'}` in your options object. You may notice that you can visit areas where there is no data displayed, to stop this add `keepInBounds: true` to the explorer options to give `explorer: {axis: 'horizontal', keepInBounds: true}`.

More information on the `explorer` options is available [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) under the table row name `explorer`.

If you would like a scroll bar feature, then another feature you could explore is a Google Charts ChartRangeFilter available [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter).
Implementation details and steps are available [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#using-controls--and-dashboards) and changes need to be made accordingly to your chart type.

Comment: still better than implementing everything @Michael