# Google chart timeline horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization, timeline

I have a timeline chart, very similar to the very first example at this page (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline).

I have activities on the Y axis (making lunch, eating, ecc) and on the X axis i have the time.

I want to enable horizontal scroll and chart zoom in/out (As mentioned in this topic [Google chart horizontal scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642373/google-chart-horizontal-scrollbar)). But i can't seem to get it working.

is there some way to enable horizontal scrolling on the timeline chart?

Many thanks.

Alessandro

Answer (score 17, accepted):

there are no standard [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#configuration-options) on the [Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) chart for scroll nor zoom.

but you could use css for horizontal scroll

set a specific width in the chart options --> `width: 1200`

and wrap it in a container with a smaller width and --> `overflow-x: scroll;`

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['timeline']
});
function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

  chart.draw(dataTable, {
    width: 1200
  });
}
```

```css
#chart_wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_wrapper">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```